# Is there anyway i could fetch the value of an array from a function(method) call without assigning it to a variable?

Tags: php, arrays

i have class method which returns an associative array with a single value in it for example.

the following method call

```
print_r($acl->getPermNameFromId(1));
```

returns the following value

```
Array ( [permName] => Access Admin )
```

now instead of accessing the value by assigning the function call to a variable like

```
$permName = $acl->getPermNameFromId(1);
$permName = $permName['permName'];
```

is there any way i could directly access the value as a string?

for example i would like to access it by

```
echo $acl->getPermNameFromId(1){$permName};
```

ofcourse the above syntax is wrong. but is there any way PHP allow me to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your going to get it using direct access. My first thought was like @Cameron.

However, the next thing I thought about is some minor trick, but your making alot of assumptions that you will always return an array with that exact key, but because you asked.

```
echo array_search('permName', array_flip($acl->getPermNameFromId(1)));
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo $acl->getPermNameFromId(1)['permName'];` *should* do the trick. It's perfectly acceptable to look up the associative array without assigning it to any particular variable.

On the other hand, assigning it to a variable doesn't really cost you anything and it probably makes your code easier to read.

Comment: that does not work it gives out following error if i use the above syntax. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in /Users/index.php on line 17`, agreed assigning it to a variable does not cost me anything. but sometome i need the function to be used within the array multiple times, that's the reason i was looking for something like this.

Comment: Huh. I thought PHP would allow that syntax. Seems to be a pretty big omission from the language.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be to add another method to your class where you could pass in the id and permName.

```
echo $acl->getPermNameWithId( 1, 'permName' );
```

Then you could use in in array selections.